# Changing Tabs is Slow/Laggy - Using Fragments

Tags: android, tabs, android-fragments, switching, performance

I have an Activity that uses tabs, and the tabs switch Fragments. The problem is that the Fragment take a few seconds to load when being created, thus switching tabs has a delay of about 1 or 2 seconds. To fix this I have been trying to find a way to display a simple Loading graphic or even a progress dialog, so that the tab changes instantly and displays something indicating things are loading until everything completes.

My `onCreateView` method of the Fragment looks like this:

```
FrameLayout fl;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    fl = (FrameLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.text_layout, container, false);

    doHeavyStuff();

    return fl;
 }
```

I tried putting `doHeavyStuff()` in `onStart()` but that did not help anything. And a Thread won't help because `doHeavyStuff()` involves manipulating views/GUI.

Any ideas on how I can display the Fragment and display "Loading" information *while* everything else loads?

Thanks!

Matt.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**In the `onActivityCreated()` :**

- Start a `progress bar`(or any progress showing UI element/s).
- Execute the `HeavyStuffDoingAsyncTask` which is explained below.

**HeavyStuffDoingAsyncTask** should have:

- `doHeayStuff()`'s logic which **doesn't update ui** in the `doInBackground` method.
- call `publishProgress()` from `doInBackground()` everytime you want to update the ui.
- Implement the UI updating logic in the `onProgressUpdate` method.
- Stop the progress bar in the `onPostExecute` method.

Good Luck.

Comment: I'm only inflating view in onCreateView() and that's also laggy. So should I change that inflating code like above for better performance?

Comment: Are you doing anything other than just inflating the view? like populating the views etc.,? If so, you should do the populating part outside of onCreateView() to avoid the laggy behaviour.

Comment: No I'm only inflating the view.
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.setting_list_layout, container, false); is the only line in onCreateView();

Comment: Post the full code as a new question. You might get some help. I would think that the laggy behaviour is because of something else.

Answer (score 3):

try to set

```
pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(no_of_fragments or pages);
```