# Switching between ActionBar.Tabs issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-progressbar

I have implemented application which downloads data from web and then shows it in two `ActionBar.Tab`s. I have one issue with it. If I switch from one tab to other one, application starts another download and while download is not finished, the app freezes. If internet connection is slow it becomes very annoying. I've decide to add `ProgressDialog` to app to show user that application is downloading data from web. I've added a piece of code which implements `ProgressDialog` to `AsyncTask` which performs the download, but that didn't help. I understand why that happens but can't find the way how to fix it  :(

Data which will be fitted into tab is represented as instance of `Fragment` class. This instance after creation will be added to `transaction`, and only after adding `mFragment` object to `transaction`, app switches to another tab.

This is the part of `tabListener` code:

```
// ...

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction transaction) {
    if (mFragment == null) {
        /*
         * Creation of ParkFragment is the reason why app locks!! Because in
         * ParkFragment data is being downloaded from web
         */
        mFragment = new ParkFragment(mUrl, mActivity);
        /*
         * mFragment can't be added to transaction until downloading is
         * finished, that's why app doesn't switch fast
         */
        transaction.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag);
    } else {
        transaction.attach(mFragment);
    }
}
```

Please, if anybody has any ideas how to implement `ProgressDialog` to avoid the delay in switching between tabs, share with it.

Thank you for reading.

Updated: I've read the answer to this question but didn't understand how that implementation will help me managing delays: [Changing Tabs is Slow/Laggy - Using Fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9237431/changing-tabs-is-slow-laggy-using-fragments).

UPD:

```
public class ParkFragment extends ListFragment {
        private ArrayList<Cinemas> cinema;
        private CinemasAdapter cinemaAdapter;
        private String url;
        private Activity activity;


        public ParkFragment (String cinema,Activity activ){
            url = cinema;
            activity = activ;
        }

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState); 
            cinema = new Handler().handle(url,activity);
            cinemaAdapter = new CinemasAdapter(activity, R.layout.movie_data_row, cinema);
            setListAdapter(cinemaAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
            Cinemas movie = cinemaAdapter.getItem(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent (activity, More.class);
            intent.putExtra("Cinemas", movie);
            intent.putExtra("data", movie.getBitmap());

            Bundle translateBundle =
                   ActivityOptions.makeCustomAnimation(activity,
                   R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_left).toBundle();
                   startActivity (intent, translateBundle);

        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `ParkFragment` you can use [content providers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) combining with [loaders](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html). Downloading data should be handled in a [service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html), when done the service inserts data into DB via content providers. And in your fragment, the loader will load the data.

There is one app named API Demos in any Android emulators, which has several examples related to content providers/ loaders/ services… The source code of its is available in Android SDK, at: `[Android SDK]/samples/android-x/ApiDemos`, in which `x` is API level.

I just think so, but if you could share your code of `ParkFragment`, perhaps there would be another problem?

---

*Edited*

In your `ParkFragment`, you can create a [`ResultReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ResultReceiver.html) (available in API 3+), put it into an `Intent` and start a service to download/ handle the `url`. The service keeps the instance of the `ResultReceiver`, when done it sends back the downloaded data to your fragment via [`send(int, Bundle)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ResultReceiver.html#send%28int,%20android.os.Bundle%29). A [`Bundle`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) can hold primitive data types such as `String`, `int`, `byte[]`… For more complex data, you create a class to hold it which implements [`Parcelable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) or [`Serializable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html).

Or with [Bound Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html), you can call the service's methods directly from within the fragment. Note that services run on main UI thread, so to avoid of [`NetworkOnMainThreadException`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html), you need something like `Thread` in your service.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've added the code of `ParkFragment`. I don't use DB in my application.. Is there any other way to fix this issue?